# Find and remove text in Word 2013

Tags: regex, ms-word, wildcard

I'm using Word 2013 and need to find text that matches this pattern:

`T-4`

Note that there's a single space before the uppercase letter, followed by a dash, then followed by a one- or two-digit number. This string is then followed by a newline. Here's an example of how it will appear in text:

```
Some text goes here T-4
Some other text goes here L-22
```

And here's what it should look like after running the search-and-replace:

```
Some text goes here
Some other text goes here
```

Here's what I came up with:

```
^w{1}[A-Z]-[0-9]{1,2}
```

> The Find What text contains a Pattern Match expression which is not valid.

How do I find these strings and remove them from a document? Thank you.

Comment: Why not use `" [A-Z]-[0-9]{1,2}"` (without quotes)?

Comment: I'm not familiar with the exact flavor of regex that Word uses; what is the `^w{1}` for? If I understand it correctly it means that you'll only match strings at the beginning of a line of the form `wT-44`... (edit: did you mean `\W` (non-word character)?)

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, thank you. That worked. I was lost on how to include the space character at start. Do you mind throwing that into an answer and I'll accept it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `^w{1}` is an unsupported construct in MS Word wildcards.

[image]

You may use a literal space instead:

```
 [A-Z]-[0-9]{1,2}
^
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for word boundaries, you can use < and > for start and end of the word.

<[A-Z]-[0-9]{1,2}>